# What does flying means metaphorically in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> **Flying** in the face of convention, the writer George Sand shocked her
>   contemporaries by taking lovers and by wearing men's clothes.

Literally flying means move through the air but in this sentence I understand that this is used metaphorically. Could anyone help me to understand what does **flying** means in this sentence.

Comment: This phrase, **[fly in the face of something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fly-in-the-face-of-something)**, means "to completely oppose, or be completely opposite to, something that most people believe or accept".

Comment: It is worthwhile reading Oald's article to fly. A lot of uses, constructions and sayings one does not suspect.http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fly_1?q=fly

Comment: Note that the term you want is *metaphorically*, not *metamorphically. (Though I suppose you could say that every metaphor may be seen as a sort of semantic metamorphosis!)

Answer (score 6):

*Fly* has been used for more than 400 years in metaphorical senses of "move with a sudden rush" and, by extension, "move with sudden violence". To *fly out* is to express oneself with sudden vehemence or anger, to *fly off the handle* is to lose one's temper or self-control, to *fly at* someone is to attack them furiously.

And *face* is used figuratively in a number of expressions to signify "confrontation" (note that *front* itself, etymologically, is the forehead and by extension the face). We speak of *facing* an enemy, of remaining brave *in the face* of danger, and of getting *in somebody's face*, to become personally belligerent.

So to *fly in the face* of something is to challenge it aggressively, to attack it, to oppose it violently.